# List all Files and Folders from Google Drive V2 using .Net

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am creating an application using Google Drive API in .Net using the Google API .Net client library.

In that list request get all files from root folder as well as from child folders and shared files. I don't want to list them all. I want list of files which are available in root folders only, not from sub folders. Hows that possible?

My code is below :

```
 FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
 var files = listRequest.Execute();
```

for that I have define scope as

```
var Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) has an optional parameter called `q` and it's used for searching:

> q string  Query string for searching files. See [Searching for
> files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) for more information about supported fields and operations.

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.Q = "'root' in parents";
var files = listRequest.Execute();
```

Would just list things within the root directory with out the children. I suggest you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) on search – it goes though how to use it.

Comment: @SrustiThakkar if it works then you should mark it as the answer.