# How to get all files in folder with Google Drive api v2

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, drive

I have the following folders in google drive:

```
Folder_1
 |-Folder_1.1
 |   |-File_1
 |   |-File_2
 |-Folder_1.2
 |   |-Folder_1.2.1
 |   |   |-File_3
 |   |-File_4
 |-File_5
```

I want to get the all files in Folder (including subfolders), i tried using query `folderID in parents`, but it only work with direct childs file, so how do i get all file in subfolders ?

```
  FilesResource.ListRequest request = _DriveService.Files.List();
  request.Q = folderID + " in parents";
  request.Spaces = "drive";
  request.PageToken = pageToken;
  var result = request.Execute();
```

Comment: maybe recursion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List all Files and Folders from Google Drive V2 using .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621948/list-all-files-and-folders-from-google-drive-v2-using-net)

Comment: did you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621948/list-all-files-and-folders-from-google-drive-v2-using-net

Comment: @Jageen in my example, Folder_1 not Root folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search sub-folders and sub-sub-folders in Google Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741520/how-do-i-search-sub-folders-and-sub-sub-folders-in-google-drive)